# Looping a replace function in python for different random outputs

Tags: python

hey there guys I appologise in advance if I can't quite articulate my problem effectively, but I'm at a point where I need help.

Basically I want to go through a list of text and replace certain elements with a random selection of words. I'm able to randomly pull the words from a list, but once I then assign them to a particular word they're all the same.

I.E I want to change this:

```
DT JJ NNP  DT JJ NN I PRP VBD JJ NN IN DT JJ NN CC VBD VBN IN RB CD 8 CD JJ
NN IN I PRP VBP IN PRP JJ NN  PRP VBP RP DT JJ NN CC I PRP VBD VBG RB RB  VB
DT NN VBD VBG RB
IN DT JJ NN CC PRP VBD VBN IN NN CC WP I PRP VBP TO VB NN
```

to this:

```
  DT JJ NNP  DT JJ shopping I PRP VBD JJ bag IN DT JJ house CC VBD VBN IN RB CD 8 CD JJ fun 
 IN I PRP VBP IN PRP JJ hatred  PRP VBP RP DT JJ bum CC I PRP VBD VBG RB RB CC VB DT
```

my code so far is this:

```
import random, re

def get_noun():
    infile = open('nouns.txt', 'r') #opens the file, preps it to be read
    nouns = infile.readlines() # reads each line of the file
    infile.close() # closes the file


    index = 0 # starts at the begining of the list

    while index < len(nouns): # first part of the counter
        nouns[index] = nouns[index].rstrip('\n') # i believe this goes through and strips each line of the /n thing, which is usually output at the end of each line
        index += 1 # counts up until it hits the final length number of the list
    noun = random.choice(nouns) # outputs a random line from the list.
    return noun

print (get_noun() + get_noun())



def work_plz():
    fun = open('struc1.txt', 'r')
    readS = fun.readlines()
    fun.close

    index = 0

    while index < len(readS): # first part of the counter
        readS[index] = readS[index].rstrip('\n') # i believe this goes through and strips each line of the /n thing, which is usually output at the end of each line
        index += 1
    okay = [w.replace('NN', get_noun()) for w in readS]
    return okay

print (work_plz() + work_plz())
```

and the output I get is this:

```
DT JJ shopping P DT JJ shopping I PRP VBD JJ shopping IN DT JJ
shopping  CC    VBD VBN IN RB CD 8 CD JJ shopping IN I PRP VBP IN PRP JJ   
shopping
```

In the program I want to replace all of the NN with different words from the get_noun() function, but it seems to only pull one into the buffer and use that for all of them.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong? I suspect it's something to do with:

```
 okay = [w.replace('NN', get_noun()) for w in readS]
```

but I don't know how to re-loop it to yield a different result for each 'NN'.

If you could help me with this I would literally be so happy!!!!

cheers.

ELlliot

EDIT:

here is the code I copied from thanasissdr:

```
 import random

nouns = 'file/path/nouns.txt'
infile = file/path/struc1.txt'

def get_noun(file):
''' This function takes as input the filepath of the file where the words you want to replace with are stored and it returns
a random word of this list. We assume that each word is stored in a new line.'''
def random_choice(lista):
    return random.choice(lista)
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    data  = f.readlines()
    return random.choice(data).rstrip()


with open(infile, 'r') as f:

big = [] ## We are going to store in this list all the words in the "infile" file.
data = f.readlines() ## Read the file.
for row in data:
    c = row.rstrip() ## Remove all the '\n' characters.'
    d = ','.join(c.split())  ## Separate all the words with comma.
    d = d.split(',') ## Storing all the words as separate strings in a list.

    ## This is the part where we replace the words that meet our criteria.
    for j in range(len(d)):
        if d[j]== 'NN':
            d[j] = get_noun(nouns)
    big.extend(d) ## join all the rows (lists) in a big list.
print (' '.join(big)) ## returns the desired output.
```

It's ALIVE. Thanks so much to you guys for all your help. I got this one to work, and being the script kiddie I am I'm going to keep it like this hahaha. I'll try my best to understand everything you guys showed me, but I'm content with having it just run as such. I hope that's not poor etiquette! All legends!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you know about dictionaries, but given you appear to be using nltk or something like it, I'm going to assume yes. Here's a version that maintains a dictionary called `Words[code]`, where code is something like 'NN'. Each entry is a list of words, so you can randomly choose one.

You can read in multiple files, per code, etc. I'm writing the files with some dummy data - you should probably delete that before you try to use it.

```
import random

with open('nouns.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    contents = """
fox dog
shopping bag # Not sure this is right. Shopping?
fun house
hatred # Or this
bum
"""
    print(contents, file=outfile)

with open('struc1.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    contents = """
DT JJ NNP  DT JJ NN I PRP VBD JJ NN IN DT JJ NN CC VBD VBN IN RB CD 8 CD JJ
NN IN I PRP VBP IN PRP JJ NN  PRP VBP RP DT JJ NN CC I PRP VBD VBG RB RB  VB
DT NN VBD VBG RB
IN DT JJ NN CC PRP VBD VBN IN NN CC WP I PRP VBP TO VB NN
"""
    print(contents, file=outfile)

Words = dict()

def get_words(path, code):

    words = Words[code] = []

    with open(path, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            words.extend(line.split('#', 1)[0].strip().split())

def random_word(code):
    wordlist = Words.get(code)
    if wordlist is None:
        return code

    return random.choice(wordlist)


def work_plz(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line_out = []
            for token in line.strip().split():
                line_out.append(random_word(token))

            print(' '.join(line_out))

get_words('nouns.txt', 'NN')
work_plz('struc1.txt')
```

Comment: Hey man I am using nltk, but I don't know about dictionaries. Only just started using the lib yesterday and still trying to wrap my head around python, as you can probably tell. Thank you so much for typing this out for me tho!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested I have created a code which does exactly what you want (`python 3`).

```
import random

nouns = '/path/to/file/containing/the/nouns.txt'
infile = '/path/to/initial/file.txt'

def get_noun(file):
    ''' This function takes as input the filepath of the file where the words you want to replace with are stored and it returns
    a random word of this list. We assume that each word is stored in a new line.''' 
    def random_choice(lista):
        return random.choice(lista)
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        return random.choice(data).rstrip()


with open(infile, 'r') as f:

    big = [] ## We are going to store in this list all the words in the "infile" file (after our desired modifications).
    data = f.readlines() ## Read the initial file.
    for row in data:
        c = row.rstrip() ## Remove all the '\n' characters.
        d = ','.join(c.split()) ## Separate all the words with comma. 
        d = d.split(',') ## Storing all the words as separate strings in a list.

        ## This is the part where we replace the words that meet our criteria.
        for j in range(len(d)):
            if d[j] == 'NN':
                d[j] = get_noun(nouns)
        big.extend(d) ## Joins all the rows (lists) in the 'big' list.
    print (' '.join(big)) ## Prints out the desired output.
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much. Unfortunately I think I'm running the latest version of Python and not 2.7. Regardless I got an error trying to compile the code. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "novgentest2.py", line 16, in <module>
    with open(infile, 'r') as f:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Comment: Hrmmmm I'm still getting the same error. I'll edit my main post to show you how I've laid the code out. Do you think you could tell me where I went wrong? 

Thanks again for your help!!!

Comment: I think it's because I'm trying to open the file twice!